# ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted. Other element would receive the click: Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have seen other questions about this error but my case is that in my program the other element should receive the click. In details: the webdriver is scrolling through google search and it must click every website it finds but the program is preventing that. How can I make it NOT search the previous site it clicked?

This is the function. The program is looping it and after the first loop it scrolls down and the error occurs:

```py
def get_info():
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[2])
description = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h3"))
).text

site = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "cite"))
)
site.click()

url=browser.current_url
#removes the https:// and the / of the url
#to get just the domain of the website
try:
    link=url.split("https://")
    link1=link[1].split("/")
    link2=link1[0]
    link3=link2.split("www.")
    real_link=link3[1]

except IndexError:
    link=url.split("https://")
    link1=link[1].split("/")
    real_link=link1[0]

time.sleep(3)
screenshot=browser.save_screenshot("photos/"+"(" + real_link + ")" + ".png")
global content
content=[]
content.append(real_link)
content.append(description)
print(content)
browser.back()
time.sleep(5)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,400)","")
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of clicked website and check every time if that link is clicked or not. Here's the demo code :

```
clicked_website=[]

url=browser.current_url
clicked_website.append(url)

# Now while clicking
if <new_url> not in clicked_website:
    <>.click()
```

This is just an **idea** how to implement. Your code is mess, I didn't understand clearly so, implement in your code by yourself.